# Закрытый блок при загрузке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Меня интересует, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы, блок уже был закрытым, если он был скрыт ранее.

То есть, у меня есть блок:

```
<div class="sliderBlock">
    <div>....some info....</div>
</div><!-- .sliderBlock -->
```

В этом блоке есть кнопка, которая может его свернуть и развернуть до определенных размеров. А именно, *открытый блок*: *350 px*, *свёрнутый блок: 50 px*;

Допустим, я открыл главную страницу и скрыл этот блок. Как мне сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другие страницы, этот слайдер был всё так же свёрнут без каких либо видимых пользователю действий?

Я пробовал сделать следующее:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var storage = $.localStorage;

   if (storage.get('_slider') == 'hide') {
        sliderBlock.css({'height': '50px'});
        hideSlider.css({'transform': 'rotate(-45deg)'})
    }
});
```

Использовал локальное хранилище для проверки. Значение `_slider` может быть пустым или принимать значение `show`, это значит что блок открытый, либо принимать значение `hide` - блок закрытый.

Когда то всё работало без видимых действий. Но сейчас почему-то загружает страницу, и блок от полного размера сворачивается до 50 px.

Может кто посоветует как решить эту проблемку?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что изначально (до загрузки скриптов) у тебя развернутое состояние у блока (в стилях).

Позже, когда твоя страница загрузится, т.е. вызовется обработчик на $(document).ready блок проходит проверку и скрывается.

Возможные решения:

1. Изменить изначальное состояние твоего блока, пусть он до загрузки всегда будет свёрнут, а после загрузки - показывается, или нет.
2. Не дожидаться загрузки jquery и других скриптов (написать пару строк javascript без jquery)
3. Использовать вместо localStorage - cookie. Тогда будет возможность на сервере (перед отрисовкой страницы) задать блоку нужное состояние.